# ElectronJS autoupdater.setFeedURL() throw exception ["Update check failed. The server sent an invalid response. Try again later."]

Tags: electron, electron-updater

I'am working on a desktop app using electron everything is working well, except for the autoUpdater.setFeedURL() method, it returns always this exception : "Update check failed. The server sent an invalid response. Try again later."

```
if(!isDev)
    {
      autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
        "url":"https://github.com/MyUsername/MyRepos/releases/"
      });
      autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn5SY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! after 2 days of headache, I found that simply I was using a deprecated version of autoUpdater, I should be using this :

```
const { autoUpdater } = require('electron-updater');
```

So what I did next is just remove the ***setFeedURL*** line and instead of ***autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()*** I used ***autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify()***

```
if(!isDev)
{
    autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify();
}
```

Comment: I've found that sometimes users have their operating system notifications snoozed or disabled, so they aren't notified when a download is ready to install. I wrote a package to present a dialog window instead to notify them if they want to relaunch and update or to do so later: https://github.com/davidwinter/electron-auto-update/

Comment: The official docs at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/updates#implementing-updates-in-your-app recommend using `const { autoUpdater } = require('electron')` instead of using "electron-updater". What do you mean by "deprecated version"? What are the differences between using electron-updater and the official way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: How did you set the feedURL in this approach?